# Internationalization/Localization issue with jstl fmt:message tag

Tags: jsp, localization, internationalization, jstl

I have a web application that needs to show in English and Arabic languages. I have added 2 separate resource bundles for English and Arabic. When it uses Arabic language with jstl format `<fmt:message key="navigation.welcome"/>` it worked fine shows the Arabic words. But when i use `<fmt:message var="itemLabel" key="navigation.welcome"/>` it does not worked and it shows the unicode value of the key/value pair. The key/value pair stored in Unicode as follow.

```
navigation.welcome = &#1571;&#1607;&#1604;&#1575; &#1608;&#1587;&#1607;&#1604;&#1575;!
```

jsp page as below.

```
<dsp:page> 
  <div id="atg_store_personalNav">
    <ul id="atg_store_personalNavItems">

     <%-- WISH LISTS LINK --%>
     <li class ="${activeTab=='WISHLIST' ? ' active' : ' '}">
     <fmt:message var="itemLabel" key="navigation.welcome"/>
     <fmt:message var="itemTitle" key="navigation_personalNavigation.linkTitle">
     <fmt:param value="${itemLabel}"/>
     </fmt:message>

    <dsp:droplet name="ProfileSecurityStatus">

        <%-- Logged in User --%>
        <dsp:oparam name="loggedIn">
        <dsp:a id="myWishList" page="/myaccount/myWishList.jsp" title="${itemTitle}" iclass="atg_store_navWishList">
          <c:out value="${itemLabel}"/>
        </dsp:a>
        </dsp:oparam>

          <%-- Anonymous user or logged in from cookie --%>
          <dsp:oparam name="default">
          <dsp:a id="myWishList" page="/global/util/loginRedirect.jsp?error=wishlistNotLoggedIn"
               title="${itemTitle}" iclass="atg_store_navWishList">
          <dsp:property bean="SessionBean.values.loginSuccessURL" value="myWishList.jsp"/>
          <c:out value="${itemLabel}"/>
        </dsp:a>
      </dsp:oparam>

     </dsp:droplet>

   </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</dsp:page>
```

var option need to used with fmt:message for later use. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Show us how you actuallly display the value stored in the itemLabel attribute.

Comment: it display as &#1571;&#1607;&#1604;&#1575; &#1608;&#1587;&#1607;&#1604;&#1575;! . Its same as the value of the key in .properties file (Also mentioned above).

Comment: I didn't ask you what it displays. I asked you to show us the JSP code used to display this value. The only code you showed stores the value in the itemLabel attribute. How do you display the value of this itemLabel attribute?

Comment: That can happen if you used `<c:out>` to display the value. It by default escapes XML special characters such as `&` to avoid XSS attacks on redisplaying user-controlled input (you've here however not redisplaying user-controlled input, right?). If you're using JSP 2.0 or newer, just omit `<c:out>` altogether and use plain EL in template text. Otherwise, set `escapeXml="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

It used  to display the output. By default c:out escapes XML special characters such as &. By adding escapeXml="false" it solved.

Comment: I was about to explain you that in an answer. Given that c:out's unique goal is to escape XML special chars, you'd better simply use `${itemLabel}` instead of `<c:out value="${itemLabel}"/>`

Comment: Thamks JB Nizet for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller or action class just write this below logic:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Then it should work.